# Have one shared page in xamarin forms stay in landscape

Tags: android, ios, xamarin

I have to make a page in a xamarin forms app go to landscape mode and stay in landscape mode. It is the shared project and used in android and iOS. Would anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Comment: What happens to the page when the orientation of the screen goes to portrait? What would the page look like? Will it exit from the screen?

Comment: @ADimaano - it would ignore the phone's actual orientation, and continue to display landscape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Supun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48817758/have-one-shared-page-in-xamarin-forms-stay-in-landscape/48818639#48818639) is on the right track, but it forces portrait mode. If you want to force landscape, this is your way to go:

**ThirdPage.xaml.cs:**

```
public new void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    MessagingCenter.Send(this, "PreventPortrait");
}

public new void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    MessagingCenter.Send(this, "AllowPortrait");
}
```

---

### Android:

**In `OnCreate()` in MainActivity:**

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ThirdPage>(this, "PreventPortrait", sender =>
{
    RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
});

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ThirdPage>(this, "AllowPortrait", sender =>
{
    RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Unspecified;
});
```

---

### iOS:

**AppDelegate.cs:**

```
public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations(UIApplication application,UIWindow forWindow)
{ 
   var mainPage = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage;
   if (mainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last() is ThirdPage)
    {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown;
    }
  return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
}
```

**ThirdPageRenderer.cs: Set Configuration back to portrait on page disappear:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ThirdPage), typeof(ThirdPageRenderer))]
namespace MyForm.iOS
{
  public class ThirdPageRenderer : PageRenderer
  { 
    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
     {
     base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
     UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SetValueForKey(NSNumber.FromNInt((int)(UIInterfaceOrientation.Landscape)), new NSString("orientation")); 
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! I did have to make one change to the code for it to work on my end. Instead of having OnAppearing and OnDisappearing be "public new void ..." I changed it to "protected override void ..."

Comment: For some reason I cannot access the Last() method on NavigationStack for iOS. Would anyone know why that is?

Comment: Thanks! Still working here in year 2020 using XF4.6

Answer (score 0):

I found this code from below link

http://www.appliedcodelog.com/2017/05/force-landscape-or-portrait-for-single.html

**XAML.CS** code

```
        public partial class ThirdPage : ContentPage
  {
      protected override void OnAppearing()
      { 
          base.OnAppearing(); 
         MessagingCenter.Send(this, "allowLandScapePortrait”);
      }
       //during page close setting back to portrait
      protected override void OnDisappearing()
      {
          base.OnDisappearing(); 
          MessagingCenter.Send(this, "preventLandScape");
      }
  }
```

**Main Activit class in android**

```
    [Activity(Label = "Main", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
 public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
  {        
  //allowing the device to change the screen orientation based on the rotation
  MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ThirdPage>(this, "allowLandScapePortrait", sender =>
  { 
   RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Unspecified;
  });

 //during page close setting back to portrait
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ThirdPage>(this, "preventLandScape", sender =>
  { 
   RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
  });
 }
```

this is for android. but that link have a ios code also